# draw the path with hector slam

Tags: slam, navigation, path, hector, action-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello every one, I am using the hector slam with hokuyo. i do have have the map but i need to see the path of the robot on Rviz
can anyone help me please

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234909/draw-the-path-with-hector-slam/) by [aziz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25874/aziz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To get the trajectory, you have to initialize hector_trajectory_server node.To do this you can directly call "geotiff_mapper.launch" file in "hector_geotiff" package. After launching this node, to visualize the path in rviz add "Path"  and select topic as /trajectory.

Edit:

Working Launch files

hector_hokuyo.launch

```
    <launch>
  <param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="true"/> 
  <param name="map_frame" value="map"/> 
  <param name="base_frame" value="base_frame"/> 
  <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
  
  <node pkg="hokuyo_node" type="hokuyo_node" name="hokuyo_node"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_2_odom" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /odom 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_2_base_footprint" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /odom /base_footprint 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_footprint_2_base_link" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_footprint /base_link 100"/> 
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_2_base_stabilized_link" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /base_stabilized 100"/> 
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_stablized_2_base_frame" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_stabilized /base_frame 100"/> 
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_frame_2_laser_link" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_frame /laser 100"/> 
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_2_nav_link" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_frame /nav 100"/>

  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d <path_to_folder>/rviz_cfg.rviz"/>

  <include file="<path_to_folder>/default_mapping.launch"/> 
  <include file="<path_to_folder>/geotiff_mapper.launch"/>

</launch>
```

default_mapping.launch

```
<launch>
  <arg name="tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name" default="scanmatcher_frame"/>
  <arg name="base_frame" default="base_frame"/>
  <arg name="odom_frame" default="base_frame"/>
  <arg name="pub_map_odom_transform" default="true"/>
  <arg name="scan_subscriber_queue_size" default="5"/>
  <arg name="scan_topic" default="scan"/>
  <arg name="map_size" default="2048"/>
  
  <node pkg="hector_mapping" type="hector_mapping" name="hector_mapping" output="screen">
    
    <!-- Frame names -->
    <param name="map_frame" value="map" />
    <param name="base_frame" value="$(arg base_frame)" />
    <param name="odom_frame" value="$(arg odom_frame)" />
    
    <!-- Tf use -->
    <param name="use_tf_scan_transformation" value="true"/>
    <param name="use_tf_pose_start_estimate" value="false"/>
    <param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="$(arg pub_map_odom_transform)"/>
    
    <!-- Map size / start point -->
    <param name="map_resolution" value="0.050"/>
    <param name="map_size" value="$(arg map_size)"/>
    <param name="map_start_x" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="map_start_y" value="0.5" />
    <param name="map_multi_res_levels" value="2" />
    
    <!-- Map update parameters -->
    <param name="update_factor_free" value="0.4"/>
    <param name="update_factor_occupied" value="0.9" />    
    <param name="map_update_distance_thresh" value="0.4"/>
    <param name="map_update_angle_thresh" value="0.06" />
    <param name="laser_z_min_value" value = "-1.0" />
    <param name="laser_z_max_value" value = "1.0" />
    
    <!-- Advertising config --> 
    <param name="advertise_map_service" value="true"/>
    
    <param name="scan_subscriber_queue_size" value="$(arg scan_subscriber_queue_size)"/>
    <param name="scan_topic" value="$(arg scan_topic)"/>
    
    <!-- Debug parameters -->
    <!--
      <param name="output_timing" value="false"/>
      <param name="pub_drawings" value="true"/>
      <param name="pub_debug_output" value="true"/>
    -->
    <param name="tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name" value="$(arg tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name)" />
  </node>
    
  <!--<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_nav_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 map nav 100"/>-->
</launch>
```

geotiff_mapper.launch

```
<launch>
  <arg name="trajectory_source_frame_name" default="/scanmatcher_frame"/>
  <arg name="trajectory_update_rate" default="4"/>
  <arg name="trajectory_publish_rate" default="0.25"/>
  <arg name="map_file_path" default="$(find hector_geotiff)/maps"/>
  <arg name="map_file_base_name" default="hector_slam_map"/>

  <node pkg="hector_trajectory_server" type="hector_trajectory_server" name="hector_trajectory_server" output="screen">
    <param name="target_frame_name" type="string" value="/map" />
    <param name="source_frame_name" type="string" value="$(arg trajectory_source_frame_name)" />
    <param name="trajectory_update_rate" type="double" value="$(arg trajectory_update_rate)" />
    <param name="trajectory_publish_rate" type="double" value="$(arg trajectory_publish_rate)" />
  </node>

  <node pkg="hector_geotiff" type="geotiff_node" name="hector_geotiff_node" output="screen" launch-prefix="nice -n 15">
    <remap from="map" to="/dynamic_map" />
    <param name="map_file_path" type="string" value="$(arg map_file_path)" />
    <param name="map_file_base_name" type="string" value="$(arg map_file_base_name)" />
    <param name="geotiff_save_period" type="double" value="0" />
    <param name="draw_background_checkerboard" type="bool" value="true" />
    <param name="draw_free_space_grid" type="bool" value="true" />
    <param name="plugins" type="string" value="hector_geotiff_plugins/TrajectoryMapWriter" />
  </node>

</launch>
```

rviz_cfg.rviz

```
Panels:
  - Class: rviz/Displays
    Help Height: 78
    Name: Displays
    Property Tree Widget:
      Expanded:
        - /Global Options1
        - /Status1
        - /LaserScan1
        - /Map1
        - /Path1
      Splitter Ratio: 0.5
    Tree Height: 463
  - Class: rviz/Selection
    Name: Selection
  - Class: rviz/Tool Properties
    Expanded:
      - /2D Pose Estimate1
      - /2D Nav Goal1
      - /Publish Point1
    Name: Tool Properties
    Splitter Ratio: 0.588679
  - Class: rviz/Views
    Expanded:
      - /Current View1
    Name: Views
    Splitter Ratio: 0.5
  - Class: rviz/Time
    Experimental: false
    Name: Time
    SyncMode: 0
    SyncSource: LaserScan
Visualization Manager:
  Class: ""
  Displays:
    - Alpha: 0.5
      Cell Size: 1
      Class: rviz/Grid
      Color: 160; 160; 164
      Enabled: true
      Line Style:
        Line Width: 0.03
        Value: Lines
      Name: Grid
      Normal Cell Count: 0
      Offset:
        X: 0
        Y: 0
        Z: 0
      Plane: XY
      Plane Cell Count: 10
      Reference Frame: <Fixed Frame>
      Value: true
    - Alpha: 1
      Autocompute Intensity Bounds: true
      Autocompute Value Bounds:
        Max Value: 0
        Min Value: 0
        Value: true
      Axis: Z
      Channel Name: intensity
      Class: rviz/LaserScan
      Color: 255; 255; 255
      Color Transformer: AxisColor
      Decay Time: 0
      Enabled: true
      Invert Rainbow: false
      Max Color: 255; 255; 255
      Max Intensity: 4096
      Min Color: 0; 0; 0
      Min Intensity: 0
      Name: LaserScan
      Position Transformer: XYZ
      Queue Size: 10
      Selectable: true
      Size (Pixels): 3
      Size (m): 0.01
      Style: Points
      Topic: /scan
      Unreliable: false
      Use Fixed Frame: true
      Use rainbow: true
      Value: true
    - Class: rviz/TF
      Enabled: true
      Frame Timeout: 15
      Frames:
        All Enabled: true
        base_footprint:
          Value: true
        base_frame:
          Value: true
        base_link:
          Value: true
        base_stabilized:
          Value: true
        laser:
          Value: true
        map:
          Value: true
        nav:
          Value: true
        odom:
          Value: true
        scanmatcher_frame:
          Value: true
      Marker Scale: 1
      Name: TF
      Show Arrows: true
      Show Axes: true
      Show Names: true
      Tree:
        map:
          odom:
            base_footprint:
              base_link:
                base_stabilized:
                  base_frame:
                    laser:
                      {}
                    nav:
                      {}
          scanmatcher_frame:
            {}
      Update Interval: 0
      Value: true
    - Alpha: 0.7
      Class: rviz/Map
      Color Scheme: map
      Draw Behind: false
      Enabled: true
      Name: Map
      Topic: /map
      Unreliable: false
      Value: true
    - Alpha: 1
      Buffer Length: 1
      Class: rviz/Path
      Color: 255; 0; 0
      Enabled: true
      Line Style: Lines
      Line Width: 0.03
      Name: Path
      Offset:
        X: 0
        Y: 0
        Z: 0
      Topic: /trajectory
      Unreliable: false
      Value: true
  Enabled: true
  Global Options:
    Background Color: 48; 48; 48
    Fixed Frame: map
    Frame Rate: 30
  Name: root
  Tools:
    - Class: rviz/Interact
      Hide Inactive Objects: true
    - Class: rviz/MoveCamera
    - Class: rviz/Select
    - Class: rviz/FocusCamera
    - Class: rviz/Measure
    - Class: rviz/SetInitialPose
      Topic: /initialpose
    - Class: rviz/SetGoal
      Topic: /move_base_simple/goal
    - Class: rviz/PublishPoint
      Single click: true
      Topic: /clicked_point
  Value: true
  Views:
    Current:
      Class: rviz/Orbit
      Distance: 12.776
      Enable Stereo Rendering:
        Stereo Eye Separation: 0.06
        Stereo Focal Distance: 1
        Swap Stereo Eyes: false
        Value: false
      Focal Point:
        X: 0.207938
        Y: 1.02128
        Z: -0.964317
      Name: Current View
      Near Clip Distance: 0.01
      Pitch: 1.5698
      Target Frame: <Fixed Frame>
      Value: Orbit (rviz)
      Yaw: 4.7004
    Saved: ~
Window Geometry:
  Displays:
    collapsed: false
  Height: 744
  Hide Left Dock: false
  Hide Right Dock: false
  QMainWindow State: 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
  Selection:
    collapsed: false
  Time:
    collapsed: false
  Tool Properties:
    collapsed: false
  Views:
    collapsed: false
  Width: 1301
  X: 65
  Y: 24
```

---

Originally posted by [gp](https://answers.ros.org/users/26916/gp/) with karma: 166 on 2016-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aziz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25874/aziz/) on 2016-05-24**:
I did what you told me but i still don't have the path, do i need to set any parameter on "geotiff_mapper.launch" file ?

**Comment by [gp](https://answers.ros.org/users/26916/gp/) on 2016-05-25**:
Can you please share your launch files or elaborate what procedure you are following. In "geotiff_mapper.launch" file, you will need to set argument "trajectory_source_frame_name" to tf for which you want to visualize the path.

**Comment by [aziz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25874/aziz/) on 2016-06-09**:
its working , thank you a lot , you saved me

**Comment by [gp](https://answers.ros.org/users/26916/gp/) on 2016-06-09**:
You are welcome.
hey accept the answer as correct by clicking the tick mark :)